# Flutter app keep crashing on iOS 14.4 and above

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am facing serious impact as my Flutter app is working on Android physical device, Android emulator, iOS emulator(iOS 14.4) and crashed **ONLY** on **iOS real devices** 5 secs later after fetching data from firebase

1. It was working perfectly before, I didn't make any changes on it but it start getting crashed now.
2. I tried to revert the changes back to previous working version but it crashed as well.

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Pubspec.yaml

```
name: aflex
description: A Community-Based On-Demand Services Marketplace Connecting Customers to Interior Designers in Malaysia.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.3.1+86
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
  flutter_datetime_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker.git
      ref: master
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  firebase_core: 1.4.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.0.1
  flutter_form_builder: ^6.0.0-nullsafety.1
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  sailor: ^0.7.1
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  outline_material_icons: ^0.1.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5555
  firebase_helpers: ^0.4.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  date_format: ^2.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.2
  location: ^4.1.1
  date_time_format: ^2.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.1
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
  map_launcher: ^2.1.1
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  flappy_search_bar: ^1.7.2
  hexcolor: ^2.0.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.3
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
  rating_dialog: ^2.0.0
  universal_platform: ^1.0.0+1
  simple_animations: ^3.0.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  bloc: ^7.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.3
  audioplayers: ^0.19.1
  stripe_payment: ^1.1.4
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.7
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  badges: ^2.0.1
  in_app_review: ^2.0.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.3
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.2.0
  mailer2: ^1.2.5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.2
  notification_permissions: ^0.5.0
  flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6
  like_button: ^2.0.2
  showcaseview: ^1.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/flags/
    - assets/mp3/

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/aflex_logo.png"
```

**Here is the crash logs when I ran on android studio using real device**

```
(lldb) 2021-08-10 17:27:07.021437+0100 Runner[28299:11146108] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '732109847689'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Runner
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 8.3.0
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(170)] Could not prepare isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(382)] Could not create root isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(576)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C2.1.1 74.125.193.94:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C2.1.1 74.125.193.94:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C3.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C3.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C4.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C4.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
8.3.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025027] Deferring to Google Analytics for Firebase for event data collection. 
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C5.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
[connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C5.1.1 74.125.193.95:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

**Here is the crash logs when I ran using Xcode on iPhone 12 Pro max simulator**

```
2021-08-10 17:12:15.277633+0100 Runner[87679:679604] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-08-10 17:12:15.334577+0100 Runner[87679:679604] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 8.3.0
2021-08-10 17:12:15.343561+0100 Runner[87679:679825] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2021-08-10 17:12:15.344198+0100 Runner[87679:679825] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2021-08-10 17:12:15.373466+0100 Runner[87679:679965] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:58955/nSXEmPeyWzc=/
2021-08-10 17:12:15.952848+0100 Runner[87679:679826] 8.3.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025027] Deferring to Google Analytics for Firebase for event data collection. 
2021-08-10 17:12:15.959014+0100 Runner[87679:679806] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.959200+0100 Runner[87679:679826] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.959672+0100 Runner[87679:679826] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.959780+0100 Runner[87679:679806] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.960313+0100 Runner[87679:679826] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.960427+0100 Runner[87679:679806] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.963161+0100 Runner[87679:679806] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.963302+0100 Runner[87679:679806] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2021-08-10 17:12:15.964322+0100 Runner[87679:679825] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-08-10 17:12:15.993368+0100 Runner[87679:679826] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator
2021-08-10 17:12:15.993545+0100 Runner[87679:679826] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '732109847689'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
2021-08-10 17:12:16.111430+0100 Runner[87679:679604] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2021-08-10 17:12:16.451663+0100 Runner[87679:679604] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Runner
2021-08-10 17:12:16.451917+0100 Runner[87679:679604] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-08-10 17:12:16.668573+0100 Runner[87679:679604] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600001a148e0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGABRT has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGBUS has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGFPE has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGILL has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGSEGV has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGSYS has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
[Crashlytics] The signal SIGTRAP has a non-Crashlytics handler (GADRegisterSignalHandlers).  This will interfere with reporting.
2021-08-10 17:12:17.543491+0100 Runner[87679:679826] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'GADRegisterExceptionHandler' in '/Users/charles/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/48A1C187-055D-4DD0-81D8-437B2D765A75/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8EA150E6-3D9E-4ECC-B46F-FD766B6E40B2/Runner.app/Runner'
2021-08-10 17:12:23.411310+0100 Runner[87679:679946] -[MTLDebugDevice newBufferWithLength:options:], line 620: error 'Buffer Validation
newBufferWith*:length 0x18000000 must not exceed 256 MB.
'
-[MTLDebugDevice newBufferWithLength:options:]:620: failed assertion `Buffer Validation
newBufferWith*:length 0x18000000 must not exceed 256 MB.
'
```

**appDelegate.swift**

```
 import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyCTaYh3j4-AIzaSyBM2XQKSXUKcr0PxyCpZzIRgD0dPEsG97g")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I believe that there is something wrong with the settings on Xcode while running release build as it is working perfectly on iPhone 12 Pro max simulator.

I wonder if anyone is facing the same issue and has a solution on it?

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: Hi @TmKVU, thanks for reminding me, I have included the crash log in this post

Comment: can you show me your appDelegate ?

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga I have included appDelegate.swift on this post, pls have a look on it

Comment: remove this FirebaseApp.configure() first and run

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga I did, but it still doesn't work

Comment: use this..  upgrade packages --major -version... this will update all the dependencies the you will need to do some change if is required in the code...

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga I did as well, but it is still crashing

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved, the culprit was because in my home page there were tons of images loaded at the same time and it is memory intensive, that's the reason why I am getting the error "stop reason = EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY ", I solved it by using optimised_cached_image (https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image) to reduce the image size and everything is working again!